# How to save ItemAttachments using EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Is it possible to save an `ItemAttachment`? For `FileAttachment` we using the following EWS Managed API Code to save,

```
   if(attachment is FileAttachment)
    {
      FileAttachment fAttachment = new FileAttachment();
      fAttachment.Load("D:\\Stream" + fAttachment.Name);
    }
```

What about For `ItemAttachment`? How can we save the `ItemAttachment` like this in a specified file?

Comment: What version of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll do you use?

Answer (score 16):

Sure this is not still a pressing matter, but I figure I will share for anyone who stumbles across this in the future as I did.

For ItemAttachments you need to load the MimeContent for the item, then you can simply write to the file/output [".eml", ".msg"]:

```
if (attachment is FileAttachment)
{
    FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;

    // Load attachment contents into a file.
    fileAttachment.Load(<file path>);
}
else // Attachment is an ItemAttachment (Email)
{
    ItemAttachment itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;

    // Load Item with additionalProperties of MimeContent
    itemAttachment.Load(EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent);

    // MimeContent.Content will give you the byte[] for the ItemAttachment
    // Now all you have to do is write the byte[] to a file
    File.WriteAllBytes(<file path>, itemAttachment.Item.MimeContent.Content);
}
```

Comment: What version of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll do you use?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I am using Microsoft EWS Managed API 2.0:  
Information:  <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx>  
Direct Link for Library: <http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42022>

Comment: No problem. This `itemAttachment.Load(EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent);` what I was missing all along.

Comment: The reason is: when you originally pull the item, it only grabs the base properties (or custom property set that you establish).  Any other properties you want have to be loaded on-demand.